# Перевести двоичные числа в восьмеричные С++

Tags: c++

Помогите написать программу, которая переводит двоичные числа в восьмеричные.
Например, вводишь "111110010", должно вывести "111110010=762".
Я не могу ее написать, потому что не понимаю как можно разбить двоичное число на триады(по три цифры), чтоб каждым трем цифрам соответствовало одно число в восьмеричной системе.
Помогите плз, дедлайн сегодня.

Comment: Вам нужно предоставить фрагмент кода как  вы это начали делать. Алгоритм простой, прочитайте эту строку в переменную, потом с правой стороной читайте по 3 символа

Comment: И откуда вы двоичные *символы* берете?

Comment: Вводите вы строку, а не "двоичное число". Соответственно, смотрите про строковые операции.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вот может теперь она задумалась о том, что что-то надо вводить? Возможно следующим вопросом будет -- а как и куда это, вводить?

Comment: @avp думать это хорошо...

Answer (score 2):

Фактически, я просто повторяю решение **@Discord**, добавив лишь проверку на то, что введенная строка состоит из 0 и 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
        std::cin.clear();
    } while ( !( std::cin >> s ) || ( s.find_first_not_of( "01" ) != std::string::npos ) ); 

    std::cout << s << " = " << std::oct << std::stoi( s, nullptr, 2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Если ввести ваше примерное число `111110010`, то вывод на консоль будет выглядеть как

```
Enter a binary number: 111110010
111110010 = 762
```

Comment: Ошибки: 'stoi' is notamember of 'std'; 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @MariaBoichenko Это у вас компилятор устаревший. Используйте тогда NULL вместо nullptr и strtol, как это показал Discord.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Самое смешное будет, когда учитель будет проверять домашнюю работу. `:-)`

Comment: @Discord Вы хотите сказать, что он также обратится на форум за подсказкой на счет решения?:)

Comment: как поменять компилятор?!??черт.

Comment: @MariaBoichenko Можно скачать Майкрософт Visual Studio Express с их сайта. Это бесплатная установка. Вы также можете пользоваться он-лайновыми компиляторами, как, например, www.ideone.com или http://melpon.org/wandbox/

Comment: огромное спасибо  [Vlad from Moscow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow) и [Discord](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/discord)

Answer (score 1):

Решение очень простое:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
    string s;
    cout << oct << strtol((getline(cin, s), s.c_str()), nullptr, 2);
}
```

Пользуйтесь на здоровье!

Comment: Я уже пыталась так делать, но происходит ошибка: nullptr was not declared in this scope. Я подключила все нужные библиотеки, но ничего не меняется. это может быть из-за того, что у меня не C++11.

Comment: null was not declared in this scope

Comment: теперь ввожу любое двоичное число, выводит 0.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве бреда

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <iomanip>
#include <climits>


int main()
{
    std::string binary ;
    while ( std::cin>>binary )
    {
        try
        {
            std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT> bs( binary ) ;
            const std::string & str = bs.to_string() ;
            const std::string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of('1') ;
            std::cout << (pos==std::string::npos?"0":str.substr(pos)) << " = " << std::oct << bs.to_ulong() << std::endl ;
            break ;
        }
        catch ( const std::invalid_argument & e )
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid argument" << std::endl ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.